# Random operators

Tags: probability-theory, random-matrices, operator-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F,P)$ be a probability spaces and $H$ be a Hilbert space. By a random operator $A$ from $H$ to $H$ we mean a linear continuous mapping from $H$ into the Frechet space $L_0^H (\Omega, \mathcal F,P)$ of all $H$-valued random variables. My question is: How Can we define $|A|$ and the adjoint $A^*$?

Answer (score 1):

We can view the random operator as a map from $H$ to the space of random variables,
$$
A \colon H\rightarrow (\Omega\rightarrow H)
$$
but also as an operator-valued random variable,
$$
X_A \colon \Omega\rightarrow (H\rightarrow H)
$$
by letting
$$
X_A(\omega)(x)=A(x)(\omega).
$$
Thus, given $\omega\in\Omega$, $X_A(\omega)$ is an operator on $H$ and hence, I guess, has an adjoint $(X_A(\omega))^*$ and an absolute value $|X_A(\omega)|$. Then you could also say that
$$
A^*(x)(\omega) = (X_A(\omega))^*$$
and
$$
|A|(x)(\omega) = |(X_A(\omega)|$$

Comment: do you have lecture note or book on this ?

Comment: No, I haven't heard of it before.